# Error while remote indexing with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'am trying to move from an ES cluster to another, in order to plan an update.

The both are same version (6.4). To achieve this, i'am using this command :

```
curl -XPOST  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  http://new_cluster/_reindex -d@reindex.json
```

And the reindex.json, is looking like this :

```
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://old_cluster:9199"
    },
    "index": "megabase.33.2",
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
      }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "megabase.33.2"
  }
}
```

I whitelisted one the new cluster the old cluster, and its works but i can't go to the end of the migration of data, because i have this error, and i don't understand what it means here :

```
{
   "took":1762,
   "timed_out":false,
   "total":8263428,
   "updated":5998,
   "created":5001,
   "deleted":0,
   "batches":11,
   "version_conflicts":0,
   "noops":0,
   "retries":{
      "bulk":0,
      "search":0
   },
   "throttled_millis":0,
   "requests_per_second":-1.0,
   "throttled_until_millis":0,
   "failures":[
      {
         "index":"megabase.33.2",
         "type":"persona",
         "id":"noYOA3IBTWbNbLJUqk6T",
         "cause":{
            "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason":"failed to parse [adr_inse]",
            "caused_by":{
               "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
               "reason":"For input string: \"2A004\""
            }
         },
         "status":400
      }
   ]
}
```

The record in the original cluster look like this :

```
{
  "took": 993,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megabase.33.2",
        "_type": "persona",
        "_id": "noYOA3IBTWbNbLJUqk6T",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "address": "Obfucated",
          "adr_inse": "2A004",
          "age": 10,
          "base": "Obfucated",
          "city": "Obfucated",
          "cp": 20167,
          "email_md5": "Obfucated",
          "fraicheur": "2020-01-12T19:39:04+01:00",
          "group": 1,
          "latlon": "Obfucated",
          "partner": "Obfucated",
          "partnerbase": 2,
          "sex": 2,
          "sms_md5": "Obfucated"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any clue on what i'am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are the mappings in your source index and destination index exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i wasn't the same, but i was thinking that reindex will recreate the mapping from source, wasn't the case

Answer (score 0):

Found out, the mapping is not well created when using only the reindex method.

So i drop the new indice, recreate mapping using elasticdump :

```
elasticdump --input=http://oldcluster/megabase.33.2 --output=http://newcluster/megabase.33.2 --type=mapping
```

Then run the previous script, everything works flawless (and was rather quick)

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured out!